# Why am I getting Application Error with Heroku Pipeline?

Tags: reactjs, github, heroku, heroku-pipelines

Setting up a new Pipeline in Heroku. I connected the app to GitHub. Starting with simple React application (via npx create-react-app) in order to see the Pipeline in action, but getting missing -a flag error. I understand that it says it is missing the target application but I don't know why. I've repeated the Pipeline settp several times to the same effect. Have read through the documentation a couple of times and not quite sure why the app is failing.

```
$ heroku logs --tail
 ›   Error: Missing required flag:
 ›     -a, --app APP  app to run command against
 ›   See more help with --help
```

First, I realized the error was because of it being a React app only, a front-end without a server. So, I spun up an Express server (via https://github.com/mateo-navarrete/create-react-express-app). However, I am getting the same error.

Can anyone offer clarifications on getting a MERN app into Heroku Pipelines? Thanks!

Comment: I might be answering my own question here, but it occurred to me that this is a Front End app only, a component. I would need to set it up as a MERN application or something.

Comment: Actually, spun up create-react-express-app https://github.com/mateo-navarrete/create-react-express-app and got the same error. Still not clear on while I am getting the missing -a flag / application error.